# How to select value if only all criteria are met?

Tags: ms-access

First time Poster here so I appoligize about the formatting and am really novice at sql, but this has me stumped. That and I am using 2016 MS Access's SQL as well.

I have a table and I want to select only the names of the people who have fulfilled all the requirements.

#### Table Chore

```
ID Name   Chore    Done
1  Joe    Sweep    Yes
2  Joe    Cook     Yes
3  Joe    Dust     Yes
4  Bill   Vacuum   No
5  Bill   Dust     Yes
6  Carrie Bathroom Yes
7  John   Cook     No
8  John   Beds     No
9  John   Laundry  Yes
10 Mary   Laundry  No
11 Mary   Sweep    No
12 Cindy  Car      Yes
13 Cindy  Garden   Yes
```

In this case, only Joe, Carrie and Cindy's names should be returned because under their name, they finished all their chores.

Help please and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use not in

```
select name from my_table  
where name not in (select name from my_table where  chore_done ='No');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure it out for the life of me!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value of `max`(done), like

```
select
   name
from
   my_table
group by name
having max(done) = -1
```

In Access, Yes/True is -1, No/False is 0, so `max`(done) is Yes

Comment: I may be confused, but shouldn't that be `Max(done)` ?

Comment: max(done) would be 0 (no).  min(done) is -1 (yes).  If you were thinking Yes = 1, you'd have to use max(abs(done))

Comment: No, I meant: if a name has `done` values of 0 and -1, `Min(done)` will be -1 too (and that would be wrong). But `Max(done)` will only be -1 when *all* values are -1.